# No matching export for import "default"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

When adding `vue-virtual-scroller` using yarn I get the following error

```bash
No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"

    node_modules/vue-virtual-scroller/dist/vue-virtual-scroller.esm.js:4:7:
      4 │ import Vue from 'vue';
        ╵        ~~~
```

I tried deleting **node-modules** and re-installing the package multiple times. But the error remains. Any idea how to solve this? Using **Vue3**.

Comment: Did you follow this [guide](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller/tree/next/packages/vue-virtual-scroller) for vue3?

Comment: @nosnart Damn, thank you. I read through the npm/yarn readme but didn't see this one with `@next` behind! You just saved me hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the installed version of the plugin is still targeting Vue 2.

You have to install `vue-virtual-scroller@next` for Vue 3 ☺️